# Creating a nice mouse over effect (includes example)?

Tags: css, mouseover

I have an image and want to create a mouse over effect as soon on the following page:

http://www.zalando.de/roxy-pam-snowboot-winterstiefel-grey-ro511c00e-101.html

To see the effect, move your mouse over the "Auf den Wunschzettel" on the right side. How are those tings done?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just look at their css? Also google return lots of resutls for cool Hover effects etc.. http://designshack.net/?p=19746

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this the 'easy way', take a look at the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) plugin qTip: [little link](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/).

If you want to build this yourself, here are the stuff you'll mostly likely need to learn:

- [CSS Positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp).
- [onmouseover](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp)/[onmouseout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseout.asp) events.
- The CSS [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property.

Hope that's enough to get you started!

**Note:** this might be possible to achieve using CSS only, but it's more paradigmatic to use JavaScript for such things.